# Solspace importer cache folder safe to clear?

Tags: solspace, solspace-importer

Simple question: the /system/expressionengine/cache/importer folder has grown to 130MB. Can I delete the contents without consequences or should I leave as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can empty it.

Importer temporarily stores the file somewhere to read and use it, whether you submit your original data file through a manual upload, remote URL, server path, etc. The EE cache folder is where these files are temporarily stored.